# npm installing packages globally

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, npm

My current working directory is :
`~/Documents/Computer Science/Web Development/5 Node/jokester`
Here, I do a `npm install colors`. My package is installed successfully. But the problem is the package is installed in `~/node_modules`. I didn't use the -g flag anywhere.

Shouldn't npm install the packages in my current directory? This node_modules folder should be present in my current directory and not at the home directory, right?

Here is some additional info:

- `npm list` gives
  `/Users/MacAir colors@1.4.0`
  which confirms that packages are installed in home directory. (MacAir is username)
- `npm get prefix` gives `/usr/local`
- `npm get location` gives `user`

I asked ChatGPT, and it suggest me to do:
`npm config set --global prefix $(pwd)/node_modules` which does not work. Packages are still installed in global.

How to get around this?

What I want to achieve is that in whatever new directory I run the command of `npm install blah` I should have the node_modules folder ONLY in that directory, and not globally like what is happening right now.

Comment: Are you sure you have a package.json in that folder, and is actually in that folder when you do your npm install?

Comment: Upon googling, I realised that was the 'package.json' was what I was missing. I solved the problem by using a `npm init` command. Thank you @JaDa